# Column marked with @Nationalized not mapping to correct column type with Hibernate 6.2.2 and MySql 5.7

Tags: hibernate

We recently upgraded our application from Spring Boot 2.3.9 to Spring Boot 3.1.0.

This included an upgrade from Hibernate 5.4.28.Final to 6.2.2.Final.

We are running MySql in AWS RDS - 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.11.2 - The default database encoding is latin1.

We noticed after the upgrade that all of the String fields that were annotated as @Nationalized had an issue.

We declared many fields like this:

```
@Nationalized
private String firstName;
```

### Before Upgrade

With Hibernate 5.4.28.Final, columns like this would show up in the generated jpa DDL like this:

```
first_name nvarchar(255)
```

And then show up in the database like this:

```
`first_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
```

### After Upgrade

With Hibernate 6.2.2.final, columns would now show up in the generated jpa DDL like this:

```
first_name varchar(255)
```

And then show up in the database like this:

```
`first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
```

I tracked this down issue down to the code in org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect lines 330-341

```
final CapacityDependentDdlType.Builder nvarcharBuilder = CapacityDependentDdlType.builder(
                        NVARCHAR,
                        columnType( NCLOB ),
                        "char",
                        this
                )
                .withTypeCapacity( getMaxVarcharLength(), "varchar($l)" )
                .withTypeCapacity( maxMediumLobLen, "mediumtext" );
        if ( getMaxVarcharLength() < maxLobLen ) {
            nvarcharBuilder.withTypeCapacity( maxLobLen, "text" );
        }
        ddlTypeRegistry.addDescriptor( nvarcharBuilder.build() );
```

The field objects are correctly being mapped to the field type of NVARCHAR (with type -9), but when the query builder tries to turn that column object into its string representation, it can never pick `nvarchar` because that isn't even an option.

The only choices the query mapper has is `varchar()`, `mediumtext` and `text` based upon the mapping above.

I know we can change the default character set and collation of our database to be utf8mb4, and we may pursue that strategy, but I am trying to understand the purpose of this change.

Why would `NVARCHAR` only map to `varchar` especially when the org.hibernate.dialect.NationalizationSupport for the mysql dialect is `EXPLICIT`

Answer (score 1):

I discussed this with the Hibernate team here

https://hibernate.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/132096-hibernate-user/topic/Hibernate.205.20to.206.20Migration.20Issue

It appears as though the mapping was inadvertently changed because MySql 8 has deprecated nvarchar.

The hibernate team agreed that the mapping should still work for MySql 5.7, and made a change to fix it.

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/6827

Instead of mapping nvarcahr -> nvarchar, the fix is to map nvarchar -> varchar character set utf8, which will work on both mysql 5.7 and mysql 8.